# The exact meaning of "may not have to do something"

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, modal-verbs

I heard this conversation from native speakers:

> "Are you going to spend the weekend at your in-law's house?"
>   "I may not have to spend the weekend at my in-law's house."

Could we say "I will probably not have to spend the weekend at my in-law's house" instead? If so or not, what is the difference in meaning?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between the English verbs _may_ and _will?_ What research have you done? If we don't know the answer to that, it is difficult to determine what you understand, and this in turn makes it difficult to explain the usage. This is why we ask that you include your own research in your questions.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I think this is a perfectly legitimate question for a non native user who is leaning English.

Comment: I understand the difference between "may" and "will", but my question is about the mixed of these modal verbs with "have to". since "may not have to do" does not make sense in my mother tongue language,I want to be sure that my understanding of the usage of this expression is correct.

Comment: @xxxxxx It is without question a legitimate and interesting question. Without knowing what if any research the OP has done, though, it's impossible to address the question in a useful way. (That doesn't mean, of course, that there are no "rep points" available in return for an answer of any sort.) It's always better if a questioner tells us "Here is what I think, and why. Here is where I learned about the word _fremilatch."_ That is why I (and many others) ask "What research have you done?" It benefits the quærents (and even the questioners.)

Comment: @MehrdadMoshaver The usage of these two verbs is important to your understanding of English. Just like your own language, English has subtleties and shades of meaning. "I _may not have to do_ sth" means: **It is equally possible that I will or will not be required to do sth." _May_ means only that an event or action _can_ take place. It implies nothing about whether or not it _will_ take place.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I agree that OP has to show the efforts that they have made to solve  the issue on their own before asking here, but I think you need to consider also that for a non native it is not always easy to find clear answers expecially when nuances of meaming are involved.

Comment: @xxxxxx The OP is an intelligent person who perhaps did not really read and understand the definition of _May_ at Cambridge.org ("used to express possibility: _She said she may decide to accept the job offer and may not"_) and who will most benefit in the long run from being encouraged to figure things out for himself. (n.b.: That entry does not tell us that the verb is "used to express _probability."_)

Comment: I try to understand the meaning of "may" at the dictionaries, but I cannot understand.

Comment: so, what is the difference between " I may not/may have to do sth"? If the both "may and may not" talk about the possibility, so what is the difference?

Comment: _May_ means that sth is _possible._ It _can_ take place. "I may have to do sth" means that it is possible that I will be required to so sth. "I may _not_ have to do sth" means that it is possible that I will _not_ be required to so sth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[May](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/may_2)*** in your sentence is used with the following connotation:

> - used for saying that there is a possibility that something is true or that something will happen:
>
>   - *There  may be an easier way of solving the problem.
>       *The injury  may have caused brain damage.
>       **I  may not be able to play on Saturday.** 
>       You  may be asked to show your passport.
>       Some fir trees  may grow up to 60 feet high.*

"*I may not have to spend the night*"  means, "*There is a possibility I will  not have  to spend the night".*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45183/discussion-on-answer-by-xxxxxx-the-exact-meaning-of-may-not-have-to-do-somethin).

Comment: Your edit is laudable, +1 . It is an important distinction for the OP to understand.